# Finding a $\mathbb{C}G$-submodule

Tags: representation-theory

**The Question.** If $G$ is isomorphic to $A_4$, and $\rho:G\to \mathrm{GL}_4(\mathbb{C})$ is given by
$$x\rho=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
\quad 
y\rho = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
identify a $1$-dimensional $\mathbb{C}G$-submodule of $V\cong\mathbb{C}^4$.

---

**My attempt thus far.** I've calculated eigenvalues of each matrix $(1,\alpha,\alpha^2)$, where $\alpha:= (-1 \pm \sqrt{3} i)/2$, in each case. Then I've found the eigenspaces; but there is no simultaneous eigenspace. Indeed, the eigenspaces for $x\rho$ are
$$U_1=\mathrm{span}\{(1,1,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\} \\
  U_2=\mathrm{span}\{(1,\alpha,\alpha^2,0)\} \\
  U_3=\mathrm{span}\{(1,\alpha^2,\alpha,0)\} $$
and for $y\rho$ they are
$$W_1=\mathrm{span}\{(0,1,1,1),(1,0,0,0)\} \\
  W_2=\mathrm{span}\{(0,1,\alpha,\alpha^2)\} \\
  W_3=\mathrm{span}\{(0,1,\alpha^2,\alpha)\}.$$

I'm not sure how to proceed here. I have checked that the given matrices are indeed a representation (by checking them on the presentation $G=\langle x,y | x^3=y^3=(xy)^2=1 \rangle$.)

Comment: Hint: these are permutation matrices, so...

Comment: @GalPorat : I was 5 sec too late :)

Comment: @N.H. couldn't have read my comment while writing an answer...

Comment: Thanks both!  I hadn't considered the intersection of $U_1$ and $W_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The representation matrices are permutation matrices, so the span of the vector $(1,1,1,1)$ is the desired $1$-dimensional $\mathbb CG$ module.